# Alt-tab behavior in Budgie task switcher

Tags: application-switcher, budgie

Most implementation of the alt-tab task switcher use a "most recent" ordering for switching to different applications.  I.e. if you hit alt-tab once, it goes to the most recent previous window/app, twice goes to the second most recent app, etc.

After installing Budgie on Ubuntu 18.04 with the Expose applet, alt-tab ordering seems arbitrary, and it doesn't let the fast swap between applications that I want.

Is there a way to change this in Budgie?

Alternatively, I know I can disable Expose and use the old switcher, but I want previews.  How do I enable those with the other switcher?

Comment: Previews applet alt + single press Tab returns to the most recent window before the currently active (all applications). Alt + Above Tab (`) does the same, but within windows of the currently active application. From there, repetedly tapping while holding alt will browse through windows. The built in alt tab (not previews) has nothing to do with previews applet and cannot be combined.

Comment: This behavior does not seem to be consistent to me.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Can't reproduce. It never fails here. Press Alt Tab, go the the previous window, press alt tab again, back to previous. repetedly doing so will always switch between last two.

Comment: It appears that the issue occurs when I hit alt-tab twice to go to the second-most-recent application.  That does not seem to work properly.  Once does seem to work.

Comment: For me the ALT-TAB behaviour is confusing, which makes it annoying because I can't work as fast as I used to. Plus, it seems to get buggy once you have some more windows open. I trid it with three windows, seems fine, but with five or more windows it does definitely not switch back to the last window.